# object doesn't support property or method $

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I have an html table in which i'am showing a result of my json object.

```
<article id="article2" style="top: 50px !important;">
            <div class="content" id="content_resultat">
                <table width="100%" class="display" id="resultats_client"></table>
            </div>
        </article>
```

I added a click button,double click button functionalities that are working fine in my dev environment

```
 $(document).on("click", "#resultats_client tbody tr", function () {
        debugger;
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                resultats_client.$("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
        });
        // double click
        $(document).on("dblclick", "#resultats_client tbody tr", function () {
         debugger;
                var row = resultats_client.row(this).data();
                if (row == undefined) return;
                var parameters = {};
                parameters["id"] = row.id;
                OREKA.SDK.formUtils1.openEntityForm("account", null, parameters, null);
            });
```

But in my Test environment i am getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8LRC.png)

Comment: `resultats_client.$()` totally looks like a typo. You never define such variable, and it's unclear why it should have jQuery as child method.

Comment: `resultats_client.$("tr.selected")` -> `$("#resultats_client tr.selected")`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm new to html/jquery so I just found this method ,use it and it worked for me in my dev environment.how i can change this?

Comment: "*You never define such variable*" but unfortunately it actually exists. It's unfortunate since it's some of IE leaking into other browsers: [Do DOM tree elements with IDs become global properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278) With that said, `resultats_client`  is still just the DOM element. What freedomn-m says is most likely what was meant here.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's worked for my click, but still my double click isn't working

Comment: @VLAZ $("#resultats_client tr.selected") has worked, but still my double click isn't working.

Comment: You cannot call a method of an object using the $ sign.

Comment: @dkum you *can*. It's just such a method does not exist on DOM nodes.